# Allow editing in iframe using shared link of files hosted in SharePoint

Tags: security, iframe

I have a requirement for a project where I am expected to create an editable share link for files hosted in SharePoint and then embed them in my web application. The point is that user should be able to edit the excel files in the iframe using the shared link.

However, when I try to implement it I always get Content Security Violation error. After further digging I find about X-Frame-Options header. Is there anything a SharePoint admin can do to disable this header or at the very least modify it such that I can add domain of my app. Viewing is not a problem only editing is.

For further context I am using Reactjs with Vitejs Client Side Rendering for my web app. I did see some attribute to disable it, but it was for an ASPX app.

Also let me know if this is even possible to do.

If none of this works, let me know any possible solution using OneDrive as well